# Hide/Remove selectionsColumn

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, grid

I want to remove or hide this without affecting the export csv. How?

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
    <settings>
        <indexField>k_id</indexField>
        <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
        <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
    </settings>
</selectionsColumn>
```

Comment: Where you want to hide or remove this one?

Comment: In my layout listing.xml ... 

I tried commenting it .. It hides the selectionsColumn but when I tried export csv Error Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class does not exist

<!-- <selectionsColumn name="ids"> <settings> <indexField>k_id</indexField> <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled> <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth> </settings> </selectionsColumn> --

Comment: Can you  tell me why you want to hide this column from the grid?

Comment: Because it is an extra column... I don't need it..

Comment: This is not extra column, Mass Actions perform on this one.

Comment: How can I hide it without affecting the export csv? @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0):

- To remove or hide the specified code without affecting the exported CSV, you can comment out the code by wrapping it in XML comments.
- This way, the code will be ignored during execution, but it will still be present in the source code for export purposes.

check this code,

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids" hidden="true">
    <settings>
        <indexField>k_id</indexField>
        <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
        <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
    </settings>
</selectionsColumn>
```

Comment: Can you provide me more details on how to do that?  I don't exactly get what you mean ... Thanks

Comment: If you mean like this, it hides the selectionsColumn but when I try the export csv.. Error. Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class  does not exist

        <!-- <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>k_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>  -->

Comment: check my updated answer. maybe it works

Comment: Element 'selectionsColumn', attribute 'hidden': The attribute 'hidden' is not allowed. @Harun

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solutions.

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
   <settings>
     <indexField>k_id</indexField>
     <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
     <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
     <visible>false</visible> 
   </settings> 
</selectionsColumn>
```

More information found here :
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/select-column/

Comment: the selectionsColumn is still visible

Comment: after above change into file, need to run cache clean, cache flush, upgrade, deploy command and then need to check.

Comment: yah. done that already.. it is still visible.. btw, this is in the admin. listing.xml 

view/adminhtml/ui_component/listing.xml